# C# - create a collection to collect the location of the last button created - and the name of the last button created

Tags: c#, .net, button

I wouldlike to know how can i keep the location of the last button created or the one the closer to end of the panel to add one just after it. Moreover I want that this new button takes the in its name the index after the last one where i f click again on the button the name will be addstrat_3

my code is :

```
    private void addstrat_i_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel3strat.Width += 200;
        Button addstrat_2 = new Button();
        panel3strat.Controls.Add(addstrat_2); 
        addstrat_2.Size = new Size(210, 41);
        addstrat_2.Location = new Point(31,89);
        addstrat_2.Visible = true;   
     }
```

In this case I put the button in a named location but I just want to create it below the last one and with a new name.

any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't specify the exact coordinates; it's a lot of work, creates a real mess, and is a nightmare to maintain as even the smallest of changes throw everything out of wack.  Just experiment with appropriate layouts for your panel such that adding a new button to the panel always adds it to the end, without needing to specify a location.

Comment: I get you, but i do not have any clue of how adding a button after all the last one, may you know how to do it 1? 
Thanks Servy for your time.

Comment: It's not at all about how you add the button, it's about configuring the panel to determine how it lays out the items within it.  Spend some time doing research as to how to configure the layout of a panel and it will become quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use simple list of button objects and keep track of it

```
List<Button> btlist= new List<Button>()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Button lastAddedBtn = null;

private void addstrat_i_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3strat.Width += 200;
    Button addstrat_2 = new Button();

    addstrat_2.Size = new Size(210, 41);
    addstrat_2.Location = new Point(31,89);
    addstrat_2.Visible = true;  

    panel3strat.Controls.Add(addstrat_2);
    lastAddedButton = addstrat2;

}
```

You could do something like this, store a reference to the last added button in a private field. You can then access its properties from elsewhere.

Comment: I do love that way ! 
do you know the way to located just below the last one created ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your buttons in a class that takes care of positioning for you. Look at `StackPanel` and try to create something similar to that.